# how to create web service Api in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

can anyone help me how to create a web service API in rails 4. I know how create web service API in ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 with action web service gem. When I am trying to use https://github.com/datanoise/actionwebservice gem in rails 4, I am getting deprecated errors.I want to upgrade my web service app. Please help me.

Comment: Please explain more about the problem and please paste code as well

Comment: you can use 'rails-api' or 'grape' gems

Comment: And you definitely want a soap API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actionwebservice is long deprecated, in favour of REST API's. At my previous job we used a [fork](https://github.com/nathanvda/actionwebservice) of actionwebservice in a rails 3 project.

Since there is no maintainer anymore for the actionwebservice gem, that fork never got merged back. If you check the fork history, a lot of people are fixing and partially updating it, but it is scattered all over the place.

Afaik none of the forks were updated to use rails 4. But using a rails 3 fork might just work.

If you really need to build a SOAP API server with Rails, imho your best option is to take a look at [Wash-out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out), but you will have to re-write your API code.

Answer (score 1):

[Rails-API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) looks promising, because [it will be part of Rails core](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19832) in Rails 5.

**Rails-API**

Rails-API is a subset of a normal Rails application, because API only applications don't require all functionality that a complete Rails application provides. so, it compatible well with old Rails versions. I don't know compatibility exactly, but I'm using it with Rails 3.2.x

There are another proper framework for this purpose, for example, [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), [Grape](http://intridea.github.io/grape/), but If you familiar with Rails, Rails-API will be the best choice.

Comment: How does this help the OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster. The OP needs an answer for Rails 4, not in 5.

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I edited my answer for that point.

Comment: Rails-API is great to minimise rails processing per request, making it more efficient for API's. However writing the API you still have to do yourself. Personally I always combine rails-api + grape. But this in no way solves having to write a SOAP API. The question was not that clear (it never mentions SOAP), but the actionwebservice gem can only serve SOAP APIs.

Comment: thank you guys for helping me. [wash_out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) is what I am looking for.